# Textsize to fill screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have countdown functionality in my app.
Every second a timer sets the current time to a TextView.
So strings are: "56:05","56:04","56:03","56:02"...

I want to make the text size as big as possible

Therefore I've written the following code.

```
private void measureAndSetText(String text) {

    Paint pMeasure = new Paint();
    Integer iWidth = _tvContent.getWidth();

    Float maxTextSize = 1000f;

    pMeasure.setTextSize(maxTextSize);
    pMeasure.setFakeBoldText(true);

    Float fCurrentWidth = pMeasure.measureText(text);

    while (fCurrentWidth > iWidth) {
        pMeasure.setTextSize(maxTextSize -= 1);
        fCurrentWidth = pMeasure.measureText(text);
    }

    _tvContent.setText(text);
    _tvContent.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, maxTextSize);
}
```

This code seems to work on my Note2, Lg Optimus 4x HD, Galay ACE and some others.
But not on my Xperia Z in landscape mode.
I guess the reason is the Full Hd Display but I don't understand why.
On the Xperia Z just the ":" sign is displayed in landscape mode. So I think the text is wrapped but I don't know why.
It would make sense to me if the text size I set to it is higher than the screen height (in landscape mode this is actually screen width -> 1080) but this isn't the case.
When I try to set a longer text -> "asdfasd asdf" it is correctly displayed.

Can someone point me to the problem?

Cheers,
Stefan

UPDATE:
I figured out that my iWidth variable which holds the width of my TextView (_tvContent.getWidth()) has the value 1770.
How can that be since my Xperia Z has just 1920x1080???

So I thought that it may be a failure in TextView.getWidth() and added the following code:

```
    Display display3 = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size3 = new Point();
    display3.getSize(size3);
    int width = size3.x;

    Display display1 = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width1 = display1.getWidth();  // deprecated
    int height1 = display1.getHeight();  // deprecated


    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    Integer iWidth = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
    int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

Results:

Point(1080, 1776)

Display id 0: DisplayInfo{"Integrierter Bildschirm", app 1080 x 1776, real 1080 x 1920, largest app 1794 x 1701, smallest app 1080 x 1005, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 480, 442.451 x 443.345 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}, DisplayMetrics{density=3.0, width=1080, height=1776, scaledDensity=3.0, xdpi=442.451, ydpi=443.345}, isValid=true

Is this a Bug on site of Sony?

Answer (score 0):

After I implemented my own TextView with its own OnDraw I've seen that there is an error in LogCat: ERROR/OpenGLRenderer(2503): Font size to large to fit in cache.

After a short research I figgured out that this is really a Bug in Android.

Addding this line to my custom TextView did the trick for me:

```
this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```